# iloc function usage in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Why does the following error out? What does the notation 
`s1.iloc[:,0].min()` stand for?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
s1 = pd.Series(np.random.rand(5), index=list(range(0, 10, 2)))
s1.iloc[:,0].min()


Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-324-b57fa06dca84>", line 1, in <module>
    s1.iloc[:,0].min()

  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1325, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)

  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1662, in _getitem_tuple
    self._has_valid_tuple(tup)

  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 188, in _has_valid_tuple
    raise IndexingError('Too many indexers')

IndexingError: Too many indexers
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **series** (`pd.Series`) object is one-dimensional. It consists of an array-like container of items together with an index.

Therefore, like any one-dimensional array, only one index is permitted.

For the minimum value of a series, use `s1.min()`.

The syntax `x.iloc[:, 0].min()` is used where `x` is a **dataframe** (`pd.DataFrame`). In other words, it is used to calculate the minimum of the first column across all rows.

Comment: "only one index is permitted": Series can be multiIndexed though?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, It's still a single index, but with multiple levels.